# Logic for listing out the item from array typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Input obj is

```
let arr1 = [
[[{id:1}, {id:2}],
[{id:3}, {id:4}],
[{id:5}]
]
}
```

Need a result as following

```
let op = [{id:1}, {id:3},{id:5},{id:2},{id:4}]
```

Logic is listing out based on
first item of first array then first item of second array then first item of third array then second item of first array.... it will go like this. N * N array

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: show us the code you have tried till now. Stackoverflow is not a site to let your home work done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `answer` is the function you are looking for:

```js
"use strict";
function answer(arr) {
    let op = [];
    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
        let hasSome = false;
        for (const item of arr) {
            if (item[i]) {
                op.push(item[i]);
                hasSome = true;
            }
        }
        if (!hasSome)
            return op;
        i++;
    }
}
const arr1 = [
    [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
    [{ id: 5 }]
];
console.log(answer(arr1));
```